# What are the steps to use java object/class in ColdFusion...?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Application.cfc has

```
<cfset this.javaSettings = {LoadPaths = ["/WEB-INF/lib/javaobjec.jar"], loadColdFusionClassPath = true,
  reloadOnChange = false}  >
```

index.cfm has

```
<cfobject type="Java" class="eval_g" name="myObj">
```

Comment: Is there a question in there? Using [Java Object in ColdFusion](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/using-java-objects.html).

Comment: You don't need this.javaSettings if you placed the jar in /web-inf/lib. Jars in that directory gets loaded automatically when cf starts.

Comment: Aside, if you are writing your own java library, you should review [java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) first. Class names are usually mixed case, not all lower case.